# storing user info to an array for use in a switch statment

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

the tasks I have are the options in the menu and I'm currently stuck trying to store user input ( in this case a string with the brand and size of a t-shirt) into an array to be used later in some of the other menu options.

```
namespace A4pf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int option = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("1. Add New T-shirt Details");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Edit Exisiting T-shirt detials");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Display All T-shirts in store");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Delete T-shirt information");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Exit");

            switch(option)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the T-Shirts Details. ");
                    Console.Write("Brand Name and size(eg. Thrasher-M");
                    string[] tshirtDetails = new string[12];

                    for (int i = 0; i < tshirtDetails.Length; i++)
                    {
                        tshirtDetails[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    
                    break;
                default:
                    
                    break;
                  
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        } 
     
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to move your array out of switch statement. this will make it available in every menu option since it will have larger scope.

Comment: You can also use other types of collections, like lists or dictionaries and store details in new class objects called shirts.

Comment: yea but the assignment specifically asks me to use an array

Comment: Hint: `option` need to be set before the switch statement. String input needs to be parsed as an integer to be used also.

Comment: Please describe _what_ the shirt details are. You have room for 12 strings and no information in the post on what those are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have stated you've given your array too narrow (small) of a scope.

Imagine that you live with 4 people. Each of you have your own room and you all share a common space -- the kitchen. Inside the kitchen is a refrigerator that contains food. None of you are allowed to go into each other's rooms. Roommate #1, decides that the refrigerator will go in his room. Now no one else has access to the food in the refrigerator, because the other roommates aren't allowed to enter his room. In essence, that's what has occurred when you placed the array declaration inside case #1. For each roommate to have access the refrigerator needs to be in a common place -- the kitchen. When you use "{" and "}" with statements such as "if", "for", "switch-case", etc..., you are defining a scope (ie: a room). It's good to only give as much access as is needed, but at the same time, ensure that everything that needs access to a variable (such as an array) has access to it.

Have you been introduced/taught about writing pseudo-code? Write down the steps that you need to do. Use both normal words and C# when appropriate -- using proper C# syntax isn't necessary when writing pseudo-code, but can sometimes be helpful. Initially, start high-level. Then revise it until you've broken the steps down far enough that you are able to start programming. You decide what the detail is, and how much detail is necessary.

Here's a pseudo-code example:

**Revision #1:**

```
Inform user what the program does (Console.WriteLine).

Give user 5 options. If user enters an invalid option, re-prompt user. Display these options until user selects option #5 (loop / Console.WriteLine)
1. Add New T-shirt Details
2. Edit Exisiting T-shirt detials
3. Display All T-shirts in store
4. Delete T-shirt information
5. Exit

Get user response (Console.ReadLine)

if userResponse = 1 then add new t-shirt details
else if userResponse = 2 then edit existing t-shirt details
else if userResponse = 3 then display all t-shirts in store
else if userResponse = 4 then delete t-shirt information
else if userResponse = 5 then exit the program
else user selected an option that doesn't exist
```

Now that we've got an overall idea what needs to happen, we can add more detail to the parts that aren't quite clear.

**Revision #2:**

```
Inform user what the program does (Console.WriteLine).

Give user 5 options. If user enters an invalid option, re-prompt user. Display these options until user selects option #5 (loop / Console.WriteLine)
1. Add New T-shirt Details
2. Edit Exisiting T-shirt details
3. Display All T-shirts in store
4. Delete T-shirt information
5. Exit

Get user response (Console.ReadLine)
Save user response in integer variable (name: option)
```

After looking at the 5 options I notice that I'm going to ask the user for more information (t-shirt details). How am I going to store the t-shirt details? I'll store them in a string variable. I need to store details for multiple t-shirts. What data type(s) allow me to store multiple values? I'll use an array -- a string array. How many of the 5 options need access to the t-shirt details? More than one, so I'll make sure they all have access to this array. How many t-shirts will the user enter details for? I'm not sure--the user can enter as many as he/she wants to. I'll start with 1 and resize the array as necessary.

```
string[] tshirtDetails = new string[1];
```

Let's continue adding more detail. We'll start by adding more detail for option #1.

I need to get t-shirt details. How can I let the user know that?

```
if userResponse = 1 then add new t-shirt details
{
    prompt user for t-shirt details (Console.WriteLine)     
    get t-shirt details from user (Console.ReadLine)
    store t-shirt details in array (tshirtDetails) 
}
```

Let's continue for option #2. I need to let the user edit existing t-shirt details. How will he/she know what t-shirts exist? Should I display the t-shirt details when this option is selected or should the user display the existing t-shirts prior to choosing this option? The user can use option #3 to display the existing t-shirt info if they need to.

```
else if userResponse = 2 then edit existing t-shirt details
{
    prompt user for which t-shirt details to modify (Console.WriteLine)     
    get t-shirt index from user (Console.ReadLine)
    update t-shirt details in array (tshirtDetails) 
}
```

Next, we'll add more detail for option #3. Since we're using an array we'll have to get multiple values from the variable. We'll use a loop. "for" (or "foreach") should work.

```
else if userResponse = 3 then display all t-shirts in store
{
   for each detail in tshirtDetails Console.WriteLine
}
```

Moving on to option #4. Which t-shirt detail do I need to delete? I'll need to ask the user.

```
else if userResponse = 4 then delete t-shirt information
{
    prompt user for which t-shirt details to modify (Console.WriteLine)     
    get t-shirt index from user (Console.ReadLine)
    remove t-shirt details from array (tshirtDetails)     
}
```

Option #5. This one is self-explanatory, so I don't need to add any more detail here.

```
else if userResponse = 5 then exit the program
```

What if user enters an invalid option? I'll inform them and then re-prompt for a valid option.

```
else 
    inform user of invalid option (Console.WriteLine)
```

**Revision #3:**

```
Inform user what the program does (Console.WriteLine).

Give user 5 options. If user enters an invalid option, re-prompt user. Display these options until user selects option #5 (loop / Console.WriteLine) 
1. Add New T-shirt Details
2. Edit Exisiting T-shirt details
3. Display All T-shirts in store
4. Delete T-shirt information
5. Exit

Get user response (Console.ReadLine)
Save user response in integer variable (name: option)

string[] tshirtDetails = new string[1];


if userResponse = 1 then add new t-shirt details
{
    prompt user for t-shirt details (Console.WriteLine)     
    get t-shirt details from user (Console.ReadLine)
    store t-shirt details in array (tshirtDetails) 
}
```

"Store t-shirt details in array". My array size is 1, what happens if the user enters details for three t-shirts? I better resize the array, before I add each t-shirt detail to the array. Let's add some pseudo-code for option #1 before "store t-shirt details in array (tshirtDetails)"

```
if userResponse = 1 then add new t-shirt details
{
    prompt user for t-shirt details (Console.WriteLine)     
    get t-shirt details from user (Console.ReadLine)
    resize array (tshirtDetails)
    store t-shirt details in array (tshirtDetails) 
}
```

We continue looking through the pseudo-code:

```
else if userResponse = 2 then edit existing t-shirt details
{
    prompt user for which t-shirt details to modify (Console.WriteLine)     
    get t-shirt index from user (Console.ReadLine)
    update t-shirt details in array (tshirtDetails) 
}

else if userResponse = 3 then display all t-shirts in store
{
   for each detail in tshirtDetails Console.WriteLine
}

else if userResponse = 4 then delete t-shirt information
{
    prompt user for which t-shirt details to modify (Console.WriteLine)     
    get t-shirt index from user (Console.ReadLine)
    remove t-shirt details from array (tshirtDetails)     
}

else if userResponse = 5 then exit the program

else 
    inform user of invalid option (Console.WriteLine)
```

I think that I'd like to use a "switch-case" statement instead of "if-else if-else" statements.

**Revision #4:**

```
Inform user what the program does (Console.WriteLine).

Give user 5 options. If user enters an invalid option, re-prompt user. Display these options until user selects option #5 (loop / Console.WriteLine)
1. Add New T-shirt Details
2. Edit Exisiting T-shirt details
3. Display All T-shirts in store
4. Delete T-shirt information
5. Exit

Get user response (Console.ReadLine)
Save user response in integer variable (name: option)

string[] tshirtDetails = new string[1];

switch(option)
{
    case 1:  
        //add new t-shirt details
    
        prompt user for t-shirt details (Console.WriteLine)     
        get t-shirt details from user (Console.ReadLine)
        resize array (tshirtDetails)
        store t-shirt details in array (tshirtDetails) 

    case 2:  
        //edit existing t-shirt details 
    
        prompt user for which t-shirt details to modify (Console.WriteLine)     
        get t-shirt index from user (Console.ReadLine)
        update t-shirt details in array (tshirtDetails) 
    
    case 3:  
        //display all t-shirts in store

        for each detail in tshirtDetails 
        {
           Console.WriteLine t-shirt details
        }

    case 4:  
        //delete t-shirt information
    
        prompt user for which t-shirt details to modify (Console.WriteLine)     
        get t-shirt index from user (Console.ReadLine)
        remove t-shirt details from array (tshirtDetails)    
    
    case 5:  
        //exit
        exit the program

    default:  
        //user selected an option that doesn't exist
    
        inform user of invalid option (Console.WriteLine)
}
```

I'm comfortable that I have enough detail to start programming.

```
namespace A4pf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int option = 0;
            string optionStr = string.Empty;
            string[] tshirtDetails = new string[1];

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the T-shirt Inventory Management program.\n");

            do
            {
                //re-initialize
                option = 0;

                Console.WriteLine("1. Add New T-shirt Details");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Edit Exisiting T-shirt detials");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Display All T-shirts in store");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Delete T-shirt information");
                Console.WriteLine("5. Exit");

                Console.Write("\nSelect an option: ");
                optionStr = Console.ReadLine();

                //convert to int
                Int32.TryParse(optionStr, out option);

                switch (option)
                {
                    case 1:
                        //add new t-shirt details
                        Console.Write("Please enter the T-Shirts Details. ");
                        Console.Write("Brand Name and size(eg. Thrasher-M): ");

                        //ToDo: add code

                        Console.WriteLine("\nT-shirt details saved.\n");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //edit existing t-shirt details 

                        //ToDo: add code

                        Console.WriteLine("\nT-shirt details updated.\n");

                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //display all t-shirts in store
                            
                        //ToDo: add code

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        //delete t-shirt information

                        //ToDo: add code

                        Console.WriteLine("\nT-shirt details deleted.\n");

                        break;
                    //case 5:
                        //exit

                    //    break;
                    default:
                        //user selected an option that doesn't exist

                        Console.WriteLine("\nError: Invalid option entered (" + optionStr + "). Please try again.\n");
                        break;
                }

                

            } while (option != 5);
        }
    }
}
```

You may notice that "Case 5" isn't needed because we evaluate if option = 5 in the "while" statement. I've commented it out. Since "case 5", and the code it contains isn't necessary, it can be deleted (removed).

The comment `//ToDo: add code` means that you may need to add additional C# code.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is `C#` you might as well start with some class building to store the information. See below the class `Shirt` with some basic functionality

```
public class Shirt
{
    public Shirt()
    {
        Brand=string.Empty; 
        Size=string.Empty;
    }

    public Shirt(string brand, string size)
    {
        Brand=brand;
        Size=size;
    }

    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }

    public void EditDetails()
    {
        string input;
        Console.Write($"Enter Brand [{Brand}]: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            this.Brand = input;
        }
        Console.Write($"Enter Size [{Size}]: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            this.Size = input;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Brand}-{Size}";
    }
}
```

1. Shirt contains two read/write properties, the brand and the size.
2. New shirt is initialized with empty strings (instead of `null`)
3. `ToString()` method creates a human-readable string representing the shirt details
4. `EditDetails()` function asks the user for the details from the `Console`, one by one. It also displays the existing details if any, and only assigns the new details if the user enters a non-empty string.

This class can be used in your program to keep track of all the shirts in the store. For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool done = false;
        List<Shirt> store = new List<Shirt>();
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1. Add New T-shirt Details");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Edit Existing T-shirt details");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Display All T-shirts in store");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Delete T-shirt information");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Exit");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(input, out int choice))
            {
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Shirt shirt = new Shirt();
                        shirt.EditDetails();
                        store.Add(shirt);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Shirt last = store[store.Count-1];
                        last.EditDetails();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        foreach (var item in store)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        } while (!done);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making an array in switch case 1, so every time you enter the case 1, the new array will be created and hence the previous data will be deleted. I suggest that you try moving that line above the `int option = 0`, so the current data in array will be available in other cases too, or at least move the declaration of the array outside the switch case, if you want to remove the previous data when you enter case 1.