# VB.NET book exercise that outputs monthly balances from a fixed amount deposit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm going through practice exercises from a book and am stuck on a particular example. Full disclosure, this is not an assignment or test but merely me practicing through chapters of a book called Introduction to Visual Basic so off the bat, I apologize to those who feel it is a stupid question to ask. The question goes like this,

Suppose a fixed amount of
money is deposited at the beginning of each month into an
investment paying 6% interest compounded monthly. After each
deposit is made,

**new balance] = 1.005 * [previous balance one month ago] +
[fixed amount].**

Write a program that requests the fixed amount of
the deposits as input and displays the balance after each of the
first four deposits.

Here is an attached image of the output[image: OutputImage]

I am not sure how to approach this question really.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim amount As Decimal
    amount = CDec(txtAmount.Text)
    lstResults.Items.Add(MonthlyInvestment(amount)).ToString("C")
  End Sub

  Function MonthlyInvestment(amount As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim balance As Decimal = amount
    Dim newBalance As Decimal
    Dim interestRate As Decimal = 0.06
    newBalance = 1.005 * balance + amount
    Return newBalance
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You approach it the same way you approach any programming problem, i.e. by working out the logic first and then writing code to implement that logic specifically. The first part is not a programming problem so anyone can do it. Work out the steps to do it manually, break them down to the smallest parts possible and formalise them into an algorithm. You then write code to implement that algorithm so, if you get stuck, you can tell us exactly what step you're stuck on and what that step is.

Comment: See the following post which shows how to write pseudo-code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65027733/storing-user-info-to-an-array-for-use-in-a-switch-statment/65030908#65030908 which may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example you can refer to.

```
Private count As Decimal
Private monthCount As Integer = 1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If count = 0 Then
        count = CDec(txtAmount.Text)
        lstResults.Items.Add($"Month {monthCount}:   " + count.ToString("C"))
        monthCount += 1
    Else
        lstResults.Items.Add($"Month {monthCount}:   " + MonthlyInvestment(count).ToString("C"))
        monthCount += 1
    End If
End Sub
Function MonthlyInvestment(balance As Decimal) As Decimal
    count = 1.005 * balance + CDec(txtAmount.Text)
    Return count 
End Function
```

Result of my test.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I practiced some more and tried changing my mindset when I start these problems. I want to practice all these examples so I know the functions and procedures. Hopefully, after this, I will be able to replicate some popular programs.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a TextBox control which is not the best option for accepting numeric values. My first suggestion would be to swap that out in favor of a NumericUpDown control. You can find the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown

After that what you should do is setup a For/Next loop to loop from month 2 (since month 1 is the initial deposit) to month n. Outside of your loop you should declare a variable to hold the current total and inside of your loop, you should do your calculation based on the current total.

Take a look at this example using a NumericUpDown:

```vb
Dim total = NumericUpDown1.Value
lstResults.Items.Add($"Month 1: {total:c}")
For month = 2 To 4
    total = 1.005 * total + NumericUpDown1.Value
    lstResults.Items.Add($"Month {month}: {total:c}")
Next
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2CK432

Also, quick side-note, `1.005` is not 6 percent. Not sure if that's a typo in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much david, you've been a great help

Answer (score 0):

Hi all thank you for your help. I went back and looked at my previous work and indeed as one said, breaking down these problems I was able to see a pattern. This is what I did

`Public Class Form1
Dim balance As Double = 0 'global variable, We need to access it everywhere in the project
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim originalDeposit As Double = CDbl(txtAmount.Text)
'clears the listbox and asaaign 0 to balance when the new blance is being entered
lstResults.Items.Clear()
balance = 0`

```
'  Option 1 displays results

'lstOutput.Items.Add("Month 1: " & newBalance(originalDeposit).ToString("C"))
'lstOutput.Items.Add("Month 2: " & newBalance(originalDeposit).ToString("C"))
'lstOutput.Items.Add("Month 3: " & newBalance(originalDeposit).ToString("C"))
'lstOutput.Items.Add("Month 4: " & newBalance(originalDeposit).ToString("C"))

' Option 2 - displays results

For i As Integer = 1 To 4
  lstResults.Items.Add("Month " & i & ": " & newBalance(originalDeposit).ToString("C"))
Next
```

End Sub
'calculates new balance. This function is called 4 times. It increase the balance
'and returns its new value
Function newBalance(originalDeposit As Double) As Double
balance = 1.005 * (balance) + originalDeposit
Return balance
End Function

End Class