# Using Visual Studio Form Like Excel

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I have created a Form in Visual Studio, but I'm a little lost on what happens now. If I was doing this in excel, it'd be pretty simple so I'd imagine Visual Studio is even easier.

I'm looking to have it fill in the two null boxes at the top, dependent on what buttons the user has clicked.
Board Caliper being in the First Column and the With Grain / Against Grain being in the second row and the last columns.

If X = Blank && Y = Blank, fill in Null Box with text.

Once those are filled in, along with the orientation and blade overlap, I'd like to send this data to the CS file as variables.

The logic I've come up with is ::

```
Board Caliper Buttons
    Show clicked when clicked
    If a different one is clicked, remove 'clicked' indicator of other

With Grain / Against Grain button
    Show clicked when clicked
    If a different one is clicked, remove 'clicked' indicator of other

Male Land Width = null
    When both Board Caliper and With Grain/ Against Grain buttons are clicked, find intersection box in table and load that text value into the Null box

Okay Button
    When Male Land Width/ Female Land is not null, orientation is selected, blade overlap is not null
        Send four values to CS file
```

I've attached a photo for clarity and linked to the files
https://github.com/UberGamz/FormWork
[image]

Comment: Have you tried implementing the logic you came up with?

Comment: Visual Studio and Excel do not really compare, VS is an IDE while excel is a spreadsheet manipulator. If you are familiar with Visual Basic and excel macros, you might be able to implement this logic by yourself with a little bit of digging but otherwise tough luck. Hope you didn't place all those labels manually...

Comment: _If I was doing this in excel, it'd be pretty simple so I'd imagine Visual Studio is even easier_: Your imagination deceives you.  _I'd like to send this data to the CS file as variables_: This statement makes it seem that you may have little to no programming experience. Unfortunately, SO isn't a free coding service. There are other sites where one can hire a programmer.

Comment: #BabySteps -- With the first issue in mind being the reference "how to I get it to send data". I Thought I'd be able to retrieve the data with Form1.maleLandWidthPicked.text after marking that label's modifier as "public". 
I've also tried using public strings, but the class can't reach the form, so I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, this program needs a re-design. It's not clear what you are attempting to accomplish. What problem are you trying to solve? Is there already a process in place? If so, what is the process? Will this application improve the process in some manner? Which data is static and which data needs to be input/modifiable by the user? Reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030908/10024425) on how to write pseudo-code may be beneficial.

Comment: You are correct in noticing I'm new to coding. That being said, you're probably right about needing a different design.
I NetHook I've written needs some user input. One of those inputs is a double, another is picked between two options, and the other two are pulled from a table (like you see in the photo). Based on the "Board Caliper" and "With Grain", the number is chosen.
How would you suggest accomplishing this task? TIA! By the way, my error was I was using the Form name from the file list, not the variable name I used to call the form. SMH So I can pull items from the form.

Comment: A Form sounded easier than asking for user input and then creating 120+ If/Then statements

Comment: If this isn't for a school project I recommend switching to C# which you'll find many more resources (ie: articles, posts, tutorials, etc...) for. If you're not already familiar with the basics (in some computer programming language), completing this project will be rather difficult.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but [DataGridView Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) may be of use.

Comment: Here are some more resources that may be useful: [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-7.0), [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-7.0), [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-7.0), [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-7.0). [DataTable Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Here's another one that may be useful: [ListView Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var form = new Form1();
        form.ShowDialog();
```

This will load the form.

```
        var maleLandWidth = form.maleLandWidthPicked.Text;
        var femaleLandWidth = form.femaleLandWidthPicked.Text;
        var overlap = form.OverlapTextBox.Text;
        var orientation = form.orientationSelection.Text;
```

This will pull the variables from the form if they are set to Modified : Public

```
    int? mcolumn = null;
    int? row = null;
    int? fcolumn = null;
```

This needs to be inside the form class, but outside of all the methods.

```
    private void OK_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

This will close the form when they click 'OK'

```
            for (int i = 2; i < tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(j, i).BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                }
            }
            var tempControl = tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition((int)mcolumn, (int)row).Text;
            tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition((int)mcolumn, (int)row).BackColor = Color.Teal;
            maleLandWidthPicked.Text = tempControl;
            var ftempControl = tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition((int)fcolumn, (int)row).Text;
            tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition((int)fcolumn, (int)row).BackColor = Color.Teal;
            femaleLandWidthPicked.Text = ftempControl;
```

This will go on all of your buttons

Mission Complete.

Thank you everyone for the assist.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)