# pseudocode for storing customer details in an array

Tags: vb.net

how can I do pseudocode for storing customer details in an array using bubble sort technique. I want it to store name, surname, email address and contact number.

this is what i tried

```
Pseudocode for sorting
Enter “name”
Display name
Enter “surname”
Display surname
Enter “emailadress”
Display email address
Enter “contact no”
Display contact no
Processing
```

If first of the pair>second
Of the pair Then
Swap positions
Tempvalue = arrayname(position)

Comment: What you could do is create a Class to contain the properties of a customer. I don't know how much you know about that; a quick search brings up several tutorials, e.g., [VB.Net - Classes & Objects](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_classes_objects.htm). Then you can have a `List(Of Customer)` (if you called the class "Customer") which you can do a bubble sort on. (You can use an array, say `Dim customers(9) As Customer`, or whatever, if you have to.)

Comment: Guessing this might be a homework question?  Pseudo code (in my mind at least) really is just a step by step logic flow of the program you're going to create.  It is language independent (so question why the vb.net tag).  Can be done with pen and paper as a pre-curser to actually jumping in and making the program

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030908/10024425) on pseudo-code may be helpful.