# Problem in identifying Prime Numbers using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, primes

Recently I wrote a code using Visual Basic 2010 Express which would tell the user whether the number the user has entered is prime or not.
The code I used displayed almost all the numbers correctly except ALL of 9's odd multiples e.g. 9, 27, 63, 81 and so on. It displayed these numbers as prime numbers even though each and every one of these is divisible by 3 and 9.

The code I used is:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim n, x As Integer
        For x = 2 To (n - 1)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number")
        n = Console.ReadLine()
        If n = 1 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Not Prime")
        ElseIf n = 2 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Prime")
        ElseIf n Mod x <> 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Prime")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Not Prime")
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

I tried adding an exception for 9:

```
ElseIf n mod 9 <> 0 Then
Console.WriteLine("Prime")
```

This did not work.
I want to know what I am doing wrong. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What *specifically* do you mean by "This did not work"?

Comment: Your code is not VBA.  Please update your tags to remove that for VBA and add the correct tags, probably VB.Net

Comment: Your code is also unlikely to produce the output you claim given that the testing for prime is done outside the for next loop for n.

Comment: The code only works for any n with 1 <= n <= 3 (any other hits are accidental) - Yes it will correctly tell you that 13 and 21 are prime, but even a broken clock is right twice a day.

Comment: The For loop is empty (i.e., there are no statements between `For` and `Next`. You should iterate the part with the `Mod` function.

Comment: @ScottHunter the part of code that I entered made no difference to the output.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I'm actually quite new to this. Can you please explain what you mean by iterating it with the Mod function?

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII I repeat, this code works for all other numbers EXCEPT multiples of 9

Comment: @freeflow Thank you for clarifying the tags. As for the testing of prime, I tried it inside the For Next Loop but when it ran it just showed me a series of *Prime* or *Not Prime* depending on the number. If I put the whole IF Statement inside the FOR NEXT Loop the program does not run.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII, 21 is not prime. I don't see any way for this code to generate anything, what with the `For` loop being empty and `n` not being assigned until after it. Is it supposed to be recursive or something?

Comment: @Clutch_PainX  Not running correctly is maybe because your code isn't valid for what you are trying to achieve.  I'd recommend trying a bit of googling.  Prime algorithms are not hard to find.

Comment: You must test all the x's in the For-loop. Only if all the `n Mod x` are  `<> 0` you have a prime. Currently you are testing `n Mod x <> 0` only once. The For-loop is at the completely wrong place now. It is even before you have read the user input.

Comment: @MichaelFoster oh boy ... that's what you get for quickly writing a comment at work XD - you are of course absolutely right

Comment: @Clutch_PainX You said and tried it inside the For Next Loop but then it showed you a series of Prime or Not Prime - well yes, this is the expected behavior of the code (as you have written it). For the code to work you have to put the logic inside the For Next loop, and then you have to figure out how you only get 1 Print per n and not 1 print per x

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-numbers/

Comment: @MichaelFoster that is the problem. This code DOES generate stuff. It can correctly identify all prime numbers but the problem arises when I enter any of 9's multiples. The program identifies these as prime when they are not prime.

Comment: @freeflow I understand that there are countless prime algorithms on the web but I want to understand why this algorithm does not work.

Comment: You must create the output after you have run the for-loop to create it only once. Otherwise the text will be printed at each iteration. See: [VB For loop examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=vb+for+loop&tbm=vid).

Comment: _I understand that there are countless prime algorithms on the web but I want to understand why this algorithm does not work_: Quite simply because your logic is flawed. You may consider writing some pseudo-code. If unfamiliar with how to do so, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030908/10024425).

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down, as it doesn't really find primes.

```
Dim n, x As Integer
        For x = 2 To (n - 1)
        Next
```

This is an elaborate way of setting `x` to 3. `(n - 1)` is -1, since `n` is not yet set, so it would be 0. The "loop" ends immediately since 2 is larger than -1, and then `x` gets incremented, from 2 to 3.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number")
        n = Console.ReadLine()
```

You're NOW asking what number to test for prime.

```
        If n = 1 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Not Prime")
        ElseIf n = 2 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Prime")
```

These are fine, as far as things go.

```
        ElseIf n Mod x <> 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Prime")
```

So you're asking whether the number is divisible by 3, and if it is not, then the number is prime. This is the opposite of what you're reporting, though, so I can't reconcile it.

```
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Not Prime")
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
```

So if the number IS divisible by 3, then it should indicate "Not Prime". Then you're asking for another input from the user, and not using it?

As stated in the comments, many resources for calculating primes exist. I would recommend putting it in a new method, rather than trying to do it all in Main.