# Creating a question database for a Unity quiz game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm a begginer developer and currently working on a quiz game in Unity. It's all about the Japanese writing scripts - hiragana and katakana. The player gets a Japanese character and 4 possible pronunciations. Their job is to pick the correct pronunciation. Up until now I would have all my questions (characters) and possible answers (pronunciations) in the inspector. However, that means there are 2 categories with 71 questions and each one has 71 possible answers (over 10k strings), so adding new characters makes it extremely laggy and inefficient. How can I improve it?

I mainly used Brackey's Quiz Tutorial and some other tutorials on Youtube or even ChatGPT.

I tried splitting up the questions from the answers so that they are seperate but I don't really know how.

This is my main code:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator playerAnimator;
    public Animator enemyAnimator;

    public GameObject healthBar;
    public GameObject enemyHealthBar;

    public Question[] katakanaQuestions;
    public Question[] hiraganaQuestions;

    [SerializeField] private float timeBetweenQuestions;

    private static List<Question> unansweredQuestions;

    private Question currentQuestion;

    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text factText;
    [SerializeField] private Button[] answerButtons;
  
    private int correctAnswerIndex;

    private bool isAnsweringQuestion = false;

    void Start()
    {
        LoadSelectedCategory();
        SetCurrentQuestion();
    }

    private void LoadSelectedCategory()
    {
        bool isHiraganaSelected = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("IsHiraganaSelected", 1) == 1;

        Question[] selectedQuestions = isHiraganaSelected ? hiraganaQuestions : katakanaQuestions;
        
        unansweredQuestions = selectedQuestions.ToList();
    }

    void SetCurrentQuestion()
    {
        int randomQuestionIndex = Random.Range(0, unansweredQuestions.Count);
        currentQuestion = unansweredQuestions[randomQuestionIndex];

        factText.text = currentQuestion.question;

        
        List<string> answerChoices = new List<string>();    // Tworzę listę możliwych odpowiedzi z poprawną odpowiedzią i trzema losowymi błędnymi odpowiedziami

        answerChoices.Add(currentQuestion.answers[currentQuestion.correctAnswerIndex]);  // Dodaję poprawną odpowiedź
        List<string> incorrectAnswers = currentQuestion.answers.ToList();
        
        incorrectAnswers.RemoveAt(currentQuestion.correctAnswerIndex);       // Usuwam poprawną odpowiedź
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)      // Dodaję resztę trzech przypadkowych odpowiedzi
        {
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, incorrectAnswers.Count);
            answerChoices.Add(incorrectAnswers[randomIndex]);
            incorrectAnswers.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
        }

        // Mieszanie
        int n = answerChoices.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = Random.Range(0, n + 1);
            string temp = answerChoices[k];
            answerChoices[k] = answerChoices[n];
            answerChoices[n] = temp;
        }

        // Tekst dla przycisków
        for (int i = 0; i < answerButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            answerButtons[i].GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().text = answerChoices[i];
        }

        // Poprawny indeks przycisku
        correctAnswerIndex = answerChoices.IndexOf(currentQuestion.answers[currentQuestion.correctAnswerIndex]);

    }

    public void CheckAnswer(int answerIndex)
    {
        if (isAnsweringQuestion)
        {
            Debug.Log("Wait for the next question!");
            return;
        }

        isAnsweringQuestion = true; // Gracz aktualnie odpowiada

        StartCoroutine(CheckAnswerCoroutine(answerIndex));
    }

    private IEnumerator CheckAnswerCoroutine(int answerIndex)
    {
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

        // Store the original colors of the buttons
        Color[] originalColors = new Color[answerButtons.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < answerButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            originalColors[i] = answerButtons[i].GetComponent<Image>().color;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < answerButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == correctAnswerIndex)
            {
                // Change the color of the correct answer button to a specific green color (0.1f, 0.8f, 0.1f)
                answerButtons[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(0.1f, 0.8f, 0.1f);
            }
            else if (i == answerIndex)
            {
                // Change the color of the selected (incorrect) answer button to a specific red color (0.8f, 0.1f, 0.1f)
                answerButtons[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(0.8f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); // Wait for a short time to show the button colors

        // Reset button colors to their original state
        for (int i = 0; i < answerButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            answerButtons[i].GetComponent<Image>().color = originalColors[i];
        }

        if (answerIndex == correctAnswerIndex)
        {
            Debug.Log("Correct!");

            Attack();
            enemyHealthBar.GetComponent<EnemyHealthBar>().TakeDamage(1);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Wrong answer");

            GetHit();
            healthBar.GetComponent<HealthBar>().TakeDamage(1);
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenQuestions); // Wait for the next question

        isAnsweringQuestion = false;

        SetCurrentQuestion();
    }
```

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Question
{

    public string question;
    public int correctAnswerIndex;
    public string[] answers;

}

[System.Serializable]
public class KatakanaQuestion
{
    public string question;
    public string[] answers;
    public int correctAnswerIndex;
}
```

Comment: _I'm a begginer developer and currently working on a quiz game...adding new characters makes it extremely laggy and inefficient_: As a _beginner_, did you expect to write a highly efficient application? There's no substitution or shortcut to experience. It takes years to develop one's skills. If you're not already familiar with writing _pseudo-code_, the following may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030908/10024425. You may also read some articles on _Time Complexity/Big O_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to simplify things would be to just have a list of katakana characters, a list of hiragana characters, and a list of pronunciations, all in the same order. Then you could just choose a random index and grab the character and the pronunciation using that index, then choose 3 other random indices for the incorrect options.